# Combined effects of photons occupying the same state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons

Will multiple photons occupying the same quantum state have a detectable combined effect? I mean, is there any difference in their combined property? I am assuming yes for this. How can  we determine whether there is just one or multiple photons?

Comment: Just to clarify I have followed some of the discussions and do understand that photons occupying the same space do not interact with each other at all, I was wondering if there is a perceived or detectable 'combined effect'. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to know there are multiple photons is if you see light. [In this one photon](http://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave_particle_duality_of_light_for_the_classroom_13/) at a time experiment one sees how an interference pattern typical of light is generated by the accumulation of single photons. These photons do not overlap in time as you would want, but the quantum mechanical probability functions make the wave paternt appear.

A demonstration of the overlap of the zillion of photons that make up a laser beam can be seen in [this MIT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4Ecq7hIzYU). It shows an experiment with a laser beam split in two beams, and how the interference pattern comes up on the screen, even though the individual photons are not interacting. Lasing is a quantum mechanical phenomenon, where individual photons can be guided optically through the beam they make up. What is interesting is total interference of the two beams , showing a black screen, and the explanation of where the energy of the beam goes ( back tot the lasing source) . It proves to me how complicated a classical system is, when viewed quantum mechanically.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. It really helped. I will check out the video too. 

Ok so to summarise in a layman terms: the property of the perceived light, say its intensity, can tell us in theory how many photos are co-occupying the same space/time location since that property is simply a multiple of the property of a single photon? Right ?

Again apologies if I am not using correct specific terms and have resorted to using terms such as property or intensity. I am just trying to get a handle of it 'in principle'.

Comment: Yes, the energy content of light is the sum of the energy of the photons that make it up. As photons and light move with the velocity of light, one has to define an area and calculate the energy passing through per second, for example, for light and divide by $E=hν$        where  $ν$     is the frequency of the classical light.                        4

Comment: Thank youuuu this is was more helpful than I had hoped for. Have a nice day. Miles outttt

Comment: Hi again. 
I have a related question I was hoping someone could help with:

Is it correct to say that a single photon occupies a certain amount of space or spreads over a certain amount of space. And measuring the energy content of that space tells us how many photons we have. But to determine they are co-occupying must mean we must measure the energy content of the smallest possible space which only a single photon can occupy to tell us we don't just have two photons next to each other. Correct?

Comment: And a related question; if photons are energy packets (which I understand are emitted when an electron falls to it's natural orbit) then is it energy packets that are occupying the same space?

Comment: photons are quantum mechanica entities/particles  and occupy no space, as far as we experimentally know. They are point particles in the table of elementary particle physics.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle . Quantum mechanical dynamics are necessary to understand elementary particle interactipns. Light is classical  electromagnetic energy propagating in space and caries energy per unit area  per second.. If one divides that energy by hν where  ν is he frequency of classical light one can have the average number of photons  in that light beam.

Comment: Photons have a quantum mechanica l**probability**  to be at a point in (x,y,z,t) as the video I linked demonstrates. at a point.

Comment: Thanks again , really appreciate your answer. Could I send you an email?

Comment: The story is I have a masters in philosophy and am writing a paper that includes a section on indiscernible identical entities and how we can ever know such a phenomena from an epistemological point of view. 
I am fully aware how most scientist and science students feel about the philosophical views on scientific matters but all i am trying to do is to get a high level understanding of the science behind it so that what I am writing isn't so obviously wrong.

Comment: I also do understand everyone is busy and no reason why someone on this forum should want to help.
I have saved some funds and am more than happy for you or anyone you know just to give some of their time. I appreciate it.

Comment: "Could I send you an email"  You will excuse me if I am wary of giving out an e-mail. I am already deleting ten unwanted posts a day . You yourselt  have not put an e-mail in your profile. Publishing on the net is like putting a note on the village bulletin. I am retired since 2000, and spend my time between my physics interests and the health of mine and my coevals. I spend a few hours a day on this site answering questions so I can keep my braincells working by learning new things and looking up old. If this comment line gets longer it will turn into a chat forum,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102927/discussion-between-anna-v-and-miles-esfahani).

Comment: Hi thanks for your message. I understand your concern.

Well there are two points that regularly come up with some of my enquires and these are the following:

Recent scientific views (mentioned in Hawkins recent book) suggest that some particles could come into existence from nothing. 'Nothing' not in the sense of some basic and simple initial nevertheless existing conditions, but complete nothingness. Which of course implies 'without a cause'.
The problem I have is our intuitive understanding of coming into being is about some change which requires energy.

Comment: If this assumption is correct and if the recent scientific views are also crrect then does that mean some energy outside of the existing available energy came into being ? How does that affect  the principle of conversation of energy? Unless whatever comes into being is using existing available energy which means they don't just come out of nothing.

Comment: The 2nd issue I have is whether multiple energy packets can occupy the same space time location in the sense that photons are suggested to do? Or in other words can multiple energy packets pass through each other without interacting with each other and yet just have an 'uninterested combined' effect?

Sorry if these are too basic and naive .

Comment: why don't you hit the link above that says "continue this discussion in chat." I have commented there

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise what you meant.